# Use TIF file in ArcGIS JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

I have a server in NodeJS and have a TIF file on that server. And I have client application. How can I connect TIF file on server with client. I've tried `res.sendFile(filePath)` and connected with ImageLayer from @arcgis/core. But it showed `Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0`. What's the best way to connect data on tif format. Data I'm using is from https://globalwindatlas.info/download/gis-files. I've enabled CORS on server.Thanks in advance.

---

Comment: It seems you parsed the response as a JSON on client side.

Do you use fetch, with res.json() ?

Comment: @Lionep I didn't parsed the data I just passed the url of my API to ImageryLayer

Answer (score 0):

The [ImageryLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-ImageryLayer.html) is for connecting to an [ArcGIS Image Service](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/image-service.htm).  If you want to connect to a raw image, the new [MediaLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-MediaLayer.html) can be used for images smaller than 2048x2048px as long as the browser support displaying it.  Note that the TIF format is not supported by most browsers, only in [Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Image_types#common_image_file_types), so you would probably need to convert it to a different file format.